# WebSocket.send is not a function

Tags: node.js, websocket

i am trying to setup a websocket server for Minecraft.

Code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const uuid = require('uuid')        // For later use

console.log('Worldedit Ready. On Minecraft chat, type /connect localhost:1010')
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 1010 })


wss.send(JSON.stringify({
    "header": {
      "version": 1,                     // We're using the version 1 message protocol
      "requestId": uuid.v4(),           // A unique ID for the request
      "messageType": "commandRequest",  // This is a request ...
      "messagePurpose": "subscribe"     // ... to subscribe to ...
    },
    "body": {
      "eventName": "PlayerMessage"      // ... all player messages.
    },
  }))
// On Minecraft, when you type "/connect localhost:3000" it creates a connection
wss.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('Connected')
})
wss.on('message', packet => {
    const msg = JSON.parse(packet)
    console.log(msg)
  })
```

Error:

```
TypeError: wss.send is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jerem\Documents\world edit\main.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

The tutorial I am following uses `ws.send`. Why is this returning an error? I thought `send` was a function.

Comment: You don't send using your server object?  You send to a `socket` that arrives on the `connection` event.  So, `wss.send()` is not something you can do in your code.  Instead, go into the `connection` event handler and do `socket.send()`.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while but here's a working version:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const uuid = require('uuid')        // For later use

console.log('Worldedit Ready. On Minecraft chat, type /connect localhost:1010')
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 1010 })

// On Minecraft, when you type "/connect localhost:3000" it creates a connection
wss.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('Connected')

    //send this to every new ws connection
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        "header": {
          "version": 1,                     // We're using the version 1 message protocol
          "requestId": uuid.v4(),           // A unique ID for the request
          "messageType": "commandRequest",  // This is a request ...
          "messagePurpose": "subscribe"     // ... to subscribe to ...
        },
        "body": {
          "eventName": "PlayerMessage"      // ... all player messages.
        },
    }))


    socket.on('message', packet => {
        const msg = JSON.parse(packet)
        console.log(msg)
    })
})
```

Comment: You posted a working version but never specified what was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const uuid = require('uuid')        // For later use

console.log('Worldedit Ready. On Minecraft chat, type /connect localhost:1010')
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 1010 })

// On Minecraft, when you type "/connect localhost:3000" it creates a connection
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('Connected')
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        "header": {
            "version": 1,                     // We're using the version 1 message protocol
            "requestId": uuid.v4(),           // A unique ID for the request
            "messageType": "commandRequest",  // This is a request ...
            "messagePurpose": "subscribe"     // ... to subscribe to ...
        },
        "body": {
            "eventName": "PlayerMessage"      // ... all player messages.
        },
    }))
})
wss.on('message', packet => {
    const msg = JSON.parse(packet)
    console.log(msg)
});
```

Please try this one.

Comment: Returns similar error (send is not a function)